# Beautiful Soup how to decode html json data in <script> object

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I collect text from a website which publishes short news updates. Recently the site's front-end was upgraded and now uses Angular. The historical documents load within a  element within a new Angular "news" page.

The data within this script element is html stored as JSON. It is encoded in a format that I am unfamiliar with. I have not been able to decode it. However, a Chrome Browser interprets the elements within the  element.

Extracts from the  element storing each old document is shown below:

```
 <script id="ng-agritown-state" type="application/json">

{&q;G.{{api_endpoint}}/api/v12/pages?parameters=newsId%3D343436565656&a;path=news-article&q;:{&q;body&q;:{&q;id&q;:&q;8&q;,&q;layout&q;:&q;onecol&q;,&q;info&q;:{&q;title&q;:&q;News article&q;

    ... 

    &q;&g;&l;span class=\&q;z\&q;&g;Record harvest 2020&l;/span&g;&l;/p&g;\n&l;p class=\&q;a\&q;&g;&l;span class=\&q;z\&q;&g;We are pleased to announce a record harvest in this current

    ...

    &q;isDataComponentAndIsAvailable&q;:true,&q;status&q;:{&q;refreshedTime&q;:1590993288947,&q;childComponents&q;:[],&q;params&q;:{&q;updates&q;:null,&q;cloneFrom&q;:null,&q;encoder&q;:{},&q;map&q;:null}}}]}}

</script>
```

Can anyone identify this encoding format? How can I decode it with Python / Beautiful Soup?

Comment: If you have a link to a page online that contains this type of encoding, it might be possible to say a bit more. As it stands, it looks like some sort of shorthand for HTML entities (i.e. `&q;` instead of `&quote;`) but it's unclear how or even why that would work without context. You  say you're getting this from a website, perhaps share a link?

Comment: An example of a document is shown in the below page.
I am interested in the indented part with the actual news.

https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/RGD/year-end-trading-and-covid-19-update/14495760

Comment: The `"ng-` in the script id already gives it away a bit: the encoding is Angular's custom encoding of html. Since you are after the content of the entire article, a simple search and replace won't do - you'll need to find a way to get Angular to decode it for you. The easiest way might be to get Python to load a JavaScript capable engine and simply have it render out the html you see in the browser and then use Python to access the resulting document, like using Selenium or PyV8. Those are heavy solutions though, don't use them if you need to run this script frequently or lightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This content seems to be custom encoded. You can try simple `str.replace`:

```
txt = r'''<script id="ng-agritown-state" type="application/json">

{&q;G.{{api_endpoint}}/api/v12/pages?parameters=newsId%3D343436565656&a;path=news-article&q;:{&q;body&q;:{&q;id&q;:&q;8&q;,&q;layout&q;:&q;onecol&q;,&q;info&q;:{&q;title&q;:&q;News article&q;

    ...

    &q;&g;&l;span class=\&q;z\&q;&g;Record harvest 2020&l;/span&g;&l;/p&g;\n&l;p class=\&q;a\&q;&g;&l;span class=\&q;z\&q;&g;We are pleased to announce a record harvest in this current

    ...

    &q;isDataComponentAndIsAvailable&q;:true,&q;status&q;:{&q;refreshedTime&q;:1590993288947,&q;childComponents&q;:[],&q;params&q;:{&q;updates&q;:null,&q;cloneFrom&q;:null,&q;encoder&q;:{},&q;map&q;:null}}}]}}

</script>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print( soup.script.contents[0].replace('&l;', '<').replace('&g;', '>').replace('&q;', '"') )
```

Prints:

```
{"G.{{api_endpoint}}/api/v12/pages?parameters=newsId%3D343436565656&a;path=news-article":{"body":{"id":"8","layout":"onecol","info":{"title":"News article"

    ...

    "><span class=\"z\">Record harvest 2020</span></p>\n<p class=\"a\"><span class=\"z\">We are pleased to announce a record harvest in this current

    ...

    "isDataComponentAndIsAvailable":true,"status":{"refreshedTime":1590993288947,"childComponents":[],"params":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null}}}]}}
```

Then `json`/`re` module to decode the information.

Comment: This sort of worked. The data was too dirty to convert it back to a JSON object but it gave the the data enough structure to extract the html using regex. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In line with my comment: The `"ng-` in the script id already gives it away: the encoding is Angular's custom encoding of HTML. Since you are after the content of the entire article, a simple search and replace won't do - you'll need to find a way to get Angular to decode it for you.

The easiest way is probably to get Python to load a JavaScript-capable engine and have it render out the HTML you see in the browser and then use Python to access the resulting document, like using Selenium or PyV8. Those are heavy solutions though, don't use them if you need to run this script frequently or using few resources.

The code below uses Selenium, prepare your virtual environment by:

- installing selenium `pip install selenium`
- installing the appropriate browser driver, in this case ChromeDriver, from here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
  (I just drop the executable in my script folder, on Windows)

Run this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/RGD/year-end-trading-and-covid-19-update/14495760")
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('news-article-content-body')
print(elem.text)
```

You can get this to work with other supported browsers as well, of course, as long as you get the driver as well. And it works similarly on other OSes.

If you do need to run this frequently, there's ways to get Selenium to run on a server to more quickly create the session and render the page repeatedly, but that's well beyond a single StackOverflow answer.