# How to decode Angular's custom HTML encoding with Python

Tags: python, angular, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape and parse a [London Stock Exchange news article](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/ESNT/date-for-fy-2020-results-announcement/14850033).

Almost the entire content of the site comes from a `JSON` that's consumed by `JavaScript`. However, this can be easily extracted with `BeautifulSoup` and parsed with the `JSON` module.

But the encoding of the script is a bit funky.

The `<script>` tag has an `id` of `"ng-lseg-state"`, which means this is Angular's custom HTML encoding.

For example:

```
&l;div class=\"news-body-content\"&g;&l;html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"&g;\n&l;head&g;\n&l;meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /&g;\n&l;title&g;&l;/title&g;\n&l;meta name=\"generator\"
```

I handle this with a `.replace()` chain:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/ESNT/date-for-fy-2020-results-announcement/14850033"
script = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml").find("script", {"id": "ng-lseg-state"})
article = json.loads(script.string.replace("&q;", '"'))
main_key = "G.{{api_endpoint}}/api/v1/pages?parameters=newsId%3D14850033&a;path=news-article"
article_body = article[main_key]["body"]["components"][1]["content"]["newsArticle"]["value"]
decoded_body = (
    article_body
    .replace('&l;', '<')
    .replace('&g;', '>')
    .replace('&q;', '"')
)
print(BeautifulSoup(decoded_body, "lxml").find_all("p"))
```

But there are still some characters that I'm not sure how to handle:

- `&amp;a;#160;`
- `&amp;a;amp;`
- `&amp;s;`

just to name a few.

**So, the question is, how do I deal with the rest of the chars? Or maybe there's a parser or a reliable char mapping out there that I don't know of?**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127215/beautiful-soup-how-to-decode-html-json-data-in-script-object  Same problem, same website.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr for pointing that one out. Seems like we could all benefit from a more generic solution than a chain of `.replace()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular encodes [transfer state](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState) using a special escape function located [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/61bfa3d9dfc7c9daecde098aca595b731c3312a0/packages/platform-browser/src/browser/transfer_state.ts#L12-L32):

```js
export function escapeHtml(text: string): string {
  const escapedText: {[k: string]: string} = {
    '&': '&a;',
    '"': '&q;',
    '\'': '&s;',
    '<': '&l;',
    '>': '&g;',
  };
  return text.replace(/[&"'<>]/g, s => escapedText[s]);
}

export function unescapeHtml(text: string): string {
  const unescapedText: {[k: string]: string} = {
    '&a;': '&',
    '&q;': '"',
    '&s;': '\'',
    '&l;': '<',
    '&g;': '>',
  };
  return text.replace(/&[^;]+;/g, s => unescapedText[s]);
}
```

You can reproduce the `unescapeHtml` function in python, and add `html.unescape` to resolve additionnal html entities:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html

unescapedText = {
    '&a;': '&',
    '&q;': '"',
    '&s;': '\'',
    '&l;': '<',
    '&g;': '>',
}

def unescape(str):
    for key, value in unescapedText.items():
        str = str.replace(key, value)
    return html.unescape(str)

url = "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/ESNT/date-for-fy-2020-results-announcement/14850033"
script = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml").find("script", {
    "id": "ng-lseg-state"
})
payload = json.loads(unescape(script.string))
main_key = "G.{{api_endpoint}}/api/v1/pages?parameters=newsId%3D14850033&path=news-article"
article_body = payload[main_key]["body"]["components"][1]["content"]["newsArticle"]["value"]
print(BeautifulSoup(article_body, "lxml").find_all("p"))
```

you were missing `&s;` and `&a;`

repl.it: https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/AngularTransferStateDecode